# Spago installs old version of package

Tags: purescript

spago keeps installing an old version (0.1.3) of purescript-point-free (1.0.0), is there a way to update the spago snapshot to take the latest version instead of the old one?

In pursuit and github shows the latest version (1.0.0) so i suppose it is there installable https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-point-free/1.0.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the package author hasn't found the time to publish the new version to the package set yet. No biggie, Spago allows local overrides too.

As long as the GitHub repo has a tag `v1.0.0`, you can tell Spago to use that particular version by modifying the package set in your `packages.dhall` file:

```
let upstream = https://raw.githubusercontent.com/purescript/package-sets/...

in upstream
  with point-free.version = "v1.0.0"
```

---

**NOTE 1:** The string "v1.0.0" is not magic. It just points to a Git tag in the repo. So this will work with any tag, or any branch name, or even with a specific commit SHA.

**NOTE 2:** You can override anything in the package definition, not just version.

For example:

```
let upstream = https://raw.githubusercontent.com/purescript/package-sets/...

in upstream
  with point-free.version = "experimental-branch"
  with prelude.version = "main"
  with parsers.version = "a0ab5bf63e195bf17f676e1075b4508af582927c"

  with some-lib.repo = "/my/local/repo"
  with some-lib.version = "my-branch"
  with some-lib.dependencies = ["prelude"]
```

Comment: I was using `in  upstream // { point-free = upstream.point-free // {version="v1.0.0"} }`  but that's event more compact, thanks a lot! I was also unsure why I couldn't install as pursuit showed the v1 docs i guessed it was up, is there a way to check the version of a package in spago to know if it holds the latest?

Comment: The whole package infrastructure of PureScript is currently in transition, so everything kind of half-works. The package sets are a GitHub repo, and the way to add/upgrade a package is to submit a pull request. At some point Spago will be able to do it automatically, but for now people just do it themselves. And you can just go an look inside to see which packages are which versions. For example, [here's the ursi's group](https://github.com/purescript/package-sets/blob/master/src/groups/ursi.dhall).